# How to directly assign complex numbers to a variable?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, complex-numbers, comma-operator

Using the `complex` class and library, how do I assign a complex number to a variable?

I understand that I can set the value when I first instantiate the complex number.
I also understand that I can assign one instantiated complex number to another.
How can I directly assign a complex number to a variable?

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/operators/

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    complex<double> a(1.2,3.4), b;
    cout << a; //-> (1.2,3.4)
    b = a;
    cout << b; //-> (1.2,3.4)
    b = (1.2,3.4);
    cout << b; //-> (3.4,0) <-- what the heck is this??
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the comma operator.

Comment: it will printed in this manner only see this (_The format in which they are formatted for output insertion is (real,imag)_) from your refernce. [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/operators/]

Answer (score 11):

For `(1.2,3.4)`, [built-in comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) will be called.

> In a comma expression E1, E2, the expression E1 is evaluated, its result is discarded, and its side effects are completed before evaluation of the expression E2 begins (note that a user-defined operator, cannot guarantee sequencing).
>
> The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, E2. If E2 is a temporary, the result of the expression is that temporary. If E2 is a bit-field, the result is a bit-field.

It means `1.2` will be evaluated and then discarded, at last `3.4` is returned.

So `b = (1.2,3.4);` is equivalent to `b = 3.4;`, which will call [`std::complex::operator=(const T& x)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%3D):

> Assigns `x` to the real part of the complex number. Imaginary part is set to zero.

That's why you get the result of `(3.4,0)`.

As @paddy suggested, you could solve the issue like:

```
b = {1.2,3.4};                 // copy-list-initialization (since c++11)
b = complex<double>(1.2, 3.4); // copy assignment via a temporary complex<double>
b = decltype(b)(1.2, 3.4);     // same as the above (since c++11)
```

Comment: This explains the behaviour but doesn't answer the question.  Perhaps suggest that the fix is to use `b = complex<double>(1.2, 3.4);` or even `b = decltype(b)(1.2, 3.4);`

Answer (score 7):

Try this, you can use `b={1.2, 3.4}` to assign a complex value

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    complex<double> a = {1,2};
    complex<double> b;

    b = {1.2, 3.4};

    cout << a + b << "\n"; // (2.2,5.4)

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you used your assignment operator `=` for the `std::complex` class only assigned the `real part` of the complex number.

So `b = (1.2,3.4);` is equivalent to changing the real part of `b` to `3.4` only.

To assign a complex number directly I think you can use `b = complex<double>(1.2,3.4);`

Comment: Watch your wording.  You can't say that the "assignment operator only assigns the real part", and then provide a solution that uses the assignment operator correctly.  There is more than one assignment operator for `std::complex<T>`.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%3D

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to get in on the act with this bad boy, compliments of C++14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::complex<double> b;
    b = 1.2 + 3.4i;
    std::cout << b << "\n";
}
```

Comment: 1. This ``std::literals`` namespace is giving me an error. 2. You meant to ``cout << b``, I believe? 3. I'm getting (1.2,0) as a result, after adjusting for 1 and 2.

Comment: Yeah, `b`.  You need a C++14 compiler though.